# Let G be a group and $a\in Z(G)$. Prove that $\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $a\in Z(G)$, where
>   $$
> Z(G) =\lbrace x \in G\mid xg=gx~~ \forall g\in G\}.$$ Prove that $H=\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

To show that $H$ is normal in $G$, I have to prove:

1. $H$ is non-empty.
2. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
3. $H$ is normal in $G$.

**Last part 3.** Let $a\in H$ and $x\in  G$ then $xax^{-1}=axx^{-1}=a$ (the second last equality holds since, $a\in Z(G)$ then $ag=ga$, here $g=x^{-1}\in G$).

If last part is correct, please help me to show the remaining.

Comment: @A.G My question is Please check the 3rd part. and help me to solve 1st and 2nd part. Also are the  three parts I have mentioned  are sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\langle a \rangle$ is a nonempty subgroup of $G$ is clear, because $a \in \langle a \rangle$, and by definition $\langle a \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $a$.

Your argument that $xax^{-1} = axx^{-1} = a$, shows that $xax^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$, but this is not sufficient to prove that $\langle a \rangle$ is normal. For that, we must show that $xyx^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$, where $y$ is **any** element of $\langle a \rangle$. We can do this easily: observe that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup containing $a$, and $\langle a \rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups containing $a$ (i.e., the **smallest** subgroup containing $a$), hence $\langle a \rangle \leq Z(G)$. In particular, an arbitrary element $y \in \langle a \rangle$ is in $Z(G)$. So we can argue as before: $xyx^{-1} = yxx^{-1} = y \in \langle a \rangle$.

Comment: why $xyx^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$ is required ? To show that H is normal in G
, it is not sufficient to show:    H is non-empty., H is a subgroup of G and H is normal in G.

Comment: @user1942348 Check the definition of normal subgroup: we need to show that $xyx^{-1} \in H$ for **every** $y \in H$ and every $x \in G$. The last sentence shows why $xyx^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$. The manipulation $xyx^{-1} = yxx^{-1}$ holds because $y \in Z(G)$, as demonstrated in the previous sentence. The first sentence shows that $H$ is nonempty (because it contains $a$) and is a subgroup of $G$ (by definition of $\langle a\rangle$).

Comment: @iser1942348 Just a comment...there's no need to go out of your way to show it is nonempty. If it's a subgroup, it's automatically nonempty. There's no such thing as an empty group, because a group must have an identity element.

Answer (score 1):

$g=a^{-1}$ is a particular and this does not proves that $<a>$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

**Solution :** for showing $<a>$ is normal subgroup of $G$ we need to show that  $gag^{-1}\in <a>~~\forall g\in G$.

Now since $a\in Z(G)~\implies ag=ga~~\forall g\in G$

therefore $gag^{-1}=(ga)g^{-1}=(ag)g^{-1}=a(gg^{-1}=a\in <a>$

$\implies gag^{-1}\in <a>~~\forall g\in G$

Therefore $<a>$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I have edited $g=x^{-1}$ part. Please see. Also help for 1st and 2nd part. that is H is non-empty.and H is a subgroup of G.

Comment: This shows that $gag^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$, but you need to show that $gyg^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$ for an arbitrary $y = a^n \in \langle a \rangle$.